# How is the frequency division using logic gates on this old video card happening?

Tags: digital-logic, frequency, logic-gates

I am trying to understand how the main crystal on a (very) old IBM MDA videocard, running at **16.257 MHz** is being divided into lower frequencies like the **1.80633 MHz** that its main display controller chip (MC6845) expects as a clock.

As you can see from the schema below, something needs to convert the **16.257 MHz** clock from the crystal down to a **1.80633 MHz** character clock that is fed into the display controller (the display controller chip will then calculate the hsync / vsync / .....). So focus here is on how to get from **16.257 MHz** to **1.80633 MHz**

[image]

There are lots of logic gates in the circuit, and although [I have found the schemas for the card online](http://www.minuszerodegrees.net/oa/OA%20-%20IBM%20Monochrome%20Display%20and%20Printer%20Adapter.pdf) I am lacking some understanding on how to interpret what is going on.

I've been told that the 74LS174 (U1) is responsible for that, and I am indeed seeing both the **16.257 MHz (pin 9)**, and the **1.80633 MHz (pin 3)** when using my multimeter, but I don't understand how it is doing the actual division.

I know that in the circuit 5 D-type flip flops in the 74LS174 are being used, where each output is fed back into the next flip flop input, but I don't understand how it works especially the **3.612 MHz ( = 16.257 / 4.5)** I am seeing on all output pins and the 1.80933 MHz on the first flip flop input pin (pin 3). For that input some kind of feedback loop is used involving an LS32 and LS10.

Does this construct have a name, and how can I go about understand more on the inner workings of this thing.

[image]

Comment: The 74174 is just rigged up as a 5 bit delay line. You'll have to draw out waveforms and derive the logic equations by hand. It's a bit of an ad-hoc mess (and oh! that 51pF capacitor! been there...) They don't make them like that any more... fortunately!

Comment: It's not a delay line -- it looks like it wants to be a LFSR, but it would stick at all zeros -- unless that 51pF cap is magically making it work, which I do *not* want to think about very hard on a Friday evening!

Comment: Why is that 5pF there ? I created the truth table + re-created that part of the circuit and I am getting a frequency / 9 on the outputs (as expected). But on the videocard I am getting frequency / 4.5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, there is a mistake in the schematic that needs to be corrected so things can start to make sense: U100, a 74LS32 IC is an **OR** gate instead of a **NOR** gate, despite what the little circle on its output may lead you to believe.

Once you fix that, inspecting the schematic you'll realize that you have a state machine where:

\$D_1=\overline{Q_4 + Q_5}\$
first bit becomes 1 only if 4th and 5th bits are both zero, otherwise becomes 0;

\$D_2=Q_1;  D_3=Q_2; D4=Q_3; D5=Q_4\$
higher bit simply follows previous state of lower bit

Having this in mind we can now create a table with all the states starting at reset state \$(Q_x=0, x=1...5)\$ as things change at each clock cycle:

$$
\begin{array}{c|cccc}
n_{CLK} & {Q_1} & {Q_2} & {Q_3} & {Q_4} & {Q_5} \\
\hline
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
2 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
3 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
4 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
5 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
6 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
7 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
8 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
9 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
$$

As you can see, the state machine returned to the reset state (all zeros) after 9 cycles. In addition, notice that any given flip-flop output has one 0->1 transition and one 1->0 transition along these 9 cycles. Therefore, you should see in any of the flip-flop outputs (as well as in \$D_1\$/pin 3) a signal whose frequency is the clock frequency divided by 9.

I'm not sure why you report seeing twice that frequency (f/4.5) in the flip-flop outputs. I'm wondering if it's a result of your measurement technique that may be susceptible to glitches. It would be nice to confirm that with an oscilloscope.

Comment: Thx a lot for the great answer .. makes a lot of sense. came to the same truth table on paper but got confused with the LS32 / LS10 so figured I was doing something wrong :)  re-created the circuit on a breadboard and the Qs indeed output the frequency / 9. (verified with both oscilloscope and multimeter). Will do the same on the videocard with the oscilloscope.  Also got confused with the feedback loop going into 1D but had an epiphany moment when I realised how these loops worked and the cool stuff you can do with that. Now need to figure out where this 4.5 division is coming from

Comment: I just verified it with my oscilloscope and the outputs are indeed showing 16.257 MHz / 9  = 1.80633 MHz. My multimeter keeps showing 3.612 MHz :) So my inexperience combined with an error in the schema and an error in the multimeter reading got the better of me :)

Comment: The fact that the duty cycle is not 50% (it’s 4/5) generates a second harmonic component not normally present, what must have confused your meter.

Comment: I meant to say the duty cycle is 4/9 :)